# web scraping, python, requests , downloading pdf files, authentication

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

Im new to this and iam trying to scrape a web site. Some of the html text can be accessed publicly. But I need to download some of the pdf files in the web site. I have the login details as well.

So I tried these methods.

```
#Attempt 1:

import requests, lxml.html
s = requests.session()
import BeautifulSoup

login = s.get('https://www.cottongrower.com.au/Member-Login.php')
login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')
form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
form['email'] = 'xxxxxxxx'
form['password'] = 'xxxxx'
form['contact'] = 'Log In'

s.post('https://www.cottongrower.com.au/Member-Login.php',data = form)
r = s.get('https://www.cottongrower.com.au/Content.php')

# check the pdf link is changed from 'signupdirect' to pdf url
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all('a')


for tag in tags:
     print(tag.get('href'))
```

Attempt 2:

```
from requests.auth import AuthBase
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx')
s = requests.session()
login = s.post('https://www.cottongrower.com.au/Member-Login.php',auth=auth )
r = s.get('https://www.cottongrower.com.au/Content.php')

# check the pdf link is changed from 'signupdirect' to pdf url
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all('a')
for tag in tags:
     print(tag.get('href'))
```

Before logged in element inspect for the link i need to scrape:

```
<td align="left" valign="top"><a target="_blank" href="signupredirect.php" class="issue_link">Increasing gossypol containing glands in cotton can boost plants natural defences</a><span class="smalltext"> &nbsp; (141kb)</span> </td>
```

after logged in, it should be like this

```
<a target="_blank" href="images/articles/38ef71991e839fad5437d77bd5297e99.pdf" class="issue_link">Increasing gossypol containing glands in cotton can boost plants natural defences</a>
```

For both attempts, I ended up printing signupdirect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are making it over complicated, try this code. (I have not tested it since I don't have an account)

```
from requests import Session


username = "username"

password = "password"


s = Session()

s.get("https://www.cottongrower.com.au/")

data = {"email":username,
"password":password,
"button":">",
"redirecttocontent":"1",
"website":"1"}

s.post("https://www.cottongrower.com.au/ValidateLogin.php", data=data)

r = s.get('https://www.cottongrower.com.au/Content.php')
```

Comment: Thanks Liam, It works like a charm. What I did wrong is I posted login details to MembershipLogin page, but not directly to the ValidateLogin page.Without you pointing it out, I would have never figured it out. Thanks